# Random UTC time zone with offset in Faker

Tags: javascript, timezone, utc, timezone-offset, faker

I can get random time zones with Faker https://fakerjs.dev/api/address.html#timezone

But I wish to get output with offset like:

`(UTC-05:00) Haiti`

Is possible to get those data with Faker? If not what approach use to generate valid random UTC time zone with offset?

Comment: Does it need to be an actual English Windows time zone display name, such as the one you showed? Or just something in that general format that  works with the IANA time zone Faker supplies?  If the former, then you could use [this](https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).  If the latter, then [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) with a custom string format could do the trick.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint data format can be general. If you can, please post answer with example usage of proposed https://github.com/unicode-org/cldr/blob/main/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml and I can say that this is closest answer :D